# Flutter : how get data from Realtime Database (Json imported) from firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream

This is my first attempt to use firebase with Flutter ,I am trying to get data from Realtime database stored (imported from json) like this image :

[image]

I created service like this :

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class FireBaseApi {
  Future getData() async {
    try {
      var url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/0.json';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

and used it like this :

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: FireBaseApi().getData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

### Now How can I reach to items?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set your method with `Future`

```
class FireBaseApi {
  Future getData() async {
    ...
    return response;
  }
}
```

and then you need to call this method with `asStream()` if you are calling this with `StreamBuilder` like below

```
return StreamBuilder(
 stream: FireBaseApi().getData().asStream(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: I get this error :  `type 'Future<int>' is not a subtype of type 'int'`

Comment: @Sermedmayi this will help you for `int` quetion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766101/flutter-firebase-type-futureint-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-int

Comment: @Sermedmayi and if your first problem is solved by my answer then please do upvote and kindly mark it as true thankyou

Comment: i will change the question

Answer (score 0):

To get the data use the following method:

```
Future<DataSnapshot> getItems() {
    return FirebaseDatabase().reference().child("items").once();
}
```

If you want to create a widget that reactively shows the items from your Realtime Database, use the following code:

```
    FirebaseAnimatedList(
        key: const Key("key"),
        query: FirebaseDatabase().reference().child("items"),
        itemBuilder:
            (_, DataSnapshot data, Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          // TODO update this to fit your own needs
          return Text(data.value.toString());
        },
      );
```